# gdb not found when setting up Mingw-64w in VSCode

Tags: gdb, mingw-w64

Following the documentation provided by VSCode for C++ provided on this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp, I ran into trouble when checking the MinGW installation. When I ran gdb --version I got this:
`$ gdb --version`
`-bash: gdb: command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you have followed the MinGW installation as in https://www.msys2.org/ or if you were using installer from [link to installer](https://github.com/msys2/msys2-installer/releases/download/2022-06-03/msys2-x86_64-20220603.exe) to install MYSYS then you have to **continue from step 5** to install required compiler tools use following command insted of **step 6 command**

`pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`

3. You should add the same **Installation Folder** used in step 3 of installation instruction to the system PATH variable or if you have used installer to install the MinGW find the MinGW installation directory by opening your C drive and add that path to system PATH (in my case Ex: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin)
4. **Make sure the C:\msys64\mingw64\bin is not empty**, if it's empty mostly you haven't continued from the step 5 after installing MYSYS from installer
5. After adding system PATH, close and open cmd window just type **path** in cmd and enter to make sure your MinGW path is addedd to system PATH, (you can copy paste the output to notepad/notepad++ and search MinGW to find the path)
6. Once MinGW is in the path your gdb command should work (please provide this screenshot of **path** command output, if it's still didn't work)

Comment: Right so it has worked, and I used a variation of the pacman command you mentioned in step 1:
`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdn`, which downloaded the gdn package.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add some details for newbies like me: if your gcc and g++ version work properly but gdb not - write "pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb" in msys2 ucrt64, it should download the missing parts(for some reason it took me 2 tries to download full) then you should go to Path and add address for gbd separately form gcc, it should look like: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin and C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin. Then, I guess, it would work just fine, I mean, finally gbd --version worked for me.